# ASPX/C# Chart: tooltip append a string to each point

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, tooltip

I have a Asp Chart and I want the tooltip to show the x value, the y value and an associate string to each point.

I have the following code

```
Dictionary<DateTime, Tuple<string, Double, Double>> testDic = new Dictionary<DateTime, Tuple<string, Double, Double>>();
```

My x-value is a DateTime (testDic.Keys) and my y-value is the Tuple.Item2. The string value I want to associate with each point is the Tuple.Item1.
I use LINQ to access those values:

```
        var ok = from ele in testDic
                 select ele.Value.Item2;

        var sys = from ele in testDic
                  select ele.Value.Item1;
```

I am currently using the following for my ToolTip:

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(testDic.Keys, ok.ToArray());
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "#VALY at #VALX{d}";
```

I am unable to append the string from the Tuple. I want the tooltip to show: "4.4 at 3 from XYC" where XYC is the string

How can I append a string a point to show on a chart tooltip?
Thanks!

Comment: Another question that would solve this problem: Is there a way to use "#INDEX" in a function? I can use the index in the array of string

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from below sample code which binding data manually to X and Y axis using FOR loop for show Tooltip dynamically.

```
Dictionary<DateTime, Tuple<string, Double, Double>> testDic = new Dictionary<DateTime, Tuple<string, Double, Double>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < testDic.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = testDic.ElementAt(i);

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(Convert.ToDateTime(item.Key).ToString("dd MMM yyyy"), Convert.ToString(item.Value.Item2));
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = item.Value.Item1;
    }
```

Comment: That is not what I need: I want to have the Xvariable, the YVariable and string for each point. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I showing tooltip dynamically from above code in my chart so I paste you here for your help. :) Is it coming from your above code Xvariable, Yvariable and string ??

Comment: Yes, I want to add a string to each X, Y point to show on the tooltip

Comment: Thank you Dexterity but I am getting this exception: "Y values cannot be data bound to the string object."

Comment: Plus I am trying to get the #VALX, #VALY and the string show in the tooltip: so three output... thanks!